# How to get children of Meteor publishComposite

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm stuck with Meteor's publishComposite. I don't understand what is the right way of getting children collections defined in publishComposite.

Assume I have such interfaces

```
interface IInterview {
  _id: string,
  candidateId: string,
  comments: IInterviewComments[]
}

interface IInterviewComment {
  userId: string,
  text: string
}

interface IUser {
  _id: string,
  name: string
}
```

So, with the data of some interview I also need names of comments' authors

I wrote something like this

```
publishComposite('interviews.item', function(interviewId) {
  return {
    find() {
      return InterviewCollection.find({_id: interviewId});
    },
    children: [
      find(interview) {
        const authorsIds = interview.comments.map((comment) => comment.userId);

        return UsersCollection.find({_id: {$in: authorsIds}});   
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

So, how should I get name of comment author on client? Can I simply execute `UsersCollection.findOne({_id: commentUserId})` or should I use some collection helper?

Comment: "Can I simply execute UsersCollection.findOne({_id: commentUserId})" - Yes you can

Answer (score 0):

publishComposite only publishes all relevant data to the client under their corresponding collections. You are free then to access it as you normally would, or abstract it as you see fit. There are different methods you can use for abstraction. Specific packages you might look into are `jagi:astronomy`, `dburles:collection-helpers`, or `socialize:base-model`.

If you want something that composes the data together so that when you get interviews, the comments for an interview are located on the comments property, and the author of a comment is specified on each of those comments, then I'd recommend looking into `cultofcoders:grapher`